# I want to implement a regularization technique "Shakeout" in CNTK

Tags: python, machine-learning, caffe, cntk, regularized

There is a paper "Shakeout: A New Approach to Regularized Deep Neural Network Training" which can be found here: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7920425/

A new regularization technique is introduced in this paper, which can replace dropout layers in a more functional way. I am working on a deep learning problem and for that I want to implement "Shakeout" technique, but the problem is I could not fully understand the actual pipeline from the paper. There is too much mathematics which I am still struggling to understand.

So far, I have seen one open source implementation which is based on "Caffe", but I am just a new practitioner of deep learning and just learning to use CNTK. so its not possible to start working on caffe.
Have anyone implemented "Shakeout" in cntk?
or if someone can provide a pseudo-code for shakeout?
Shakeout implementation on Caffe: https://github.com/kgl-prml/shakeout-for-caffe

Github Issue: https://github.com/kgl-prml/shakeout-for-caffe/issues/1

Comment: While this is very information, I failed to understand what you are asking exactly. Can you please elaborate your **actual question**?

Comment: I edited the question to elaborate. 
Any direction on how can I implement "Shakeout" in cntk.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick look at the paper a dense layer combined with a shakeout layer would look like the following:

```
def DenseWithShakeout(rate, c, outputs):
    weights = C.parameter((C.InferredDimension, outputs), init=C.glorot_uniform())
    bias = C.parameter(outputs)
    def shakeout(x):
        r = C.dropout(x, rate)
        signs = weights/C.abs(weights) # one day CNTK should add an actual sign operation
        return C.times(r, weights) + c * C.times(r - x, signs) + bias
    return shakeout
```

This can be used inside a `C.layers.Sequential()` statement e.g.

```
model = C.layers.Sequential([Dense(0.2, 1, 100), DenseWithShakeout(10)])
```

will create a two layer network with a shakeout layer in the middle. Note, I have not actually tried this on any real problem.